# error: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at: 0x7ffeeafe2af0 : using userDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, userdefaults

I am doing  a project in objective-c and I have to store some values in userDefaults. I am already did the same thing in the same project. It was working fine but now I am trying to add some values in userDefaults it showing error while fetch any data from userDefaults. I am adding the datas as,

```
  NSString *  totalBitValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f Bit",
                           totalValue /
                                 [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Bit"] floatValue]];

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:totalBitValue forKey:@"totalBTCValue"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setFloat:totalUSDValue forKey:@"totalUsedValue"];

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and the error as ,

> error: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at: 0x7ffeeafe2af0

I got the error in the following line,

```
 if( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CoinValue"] != nil) {
    [[self ValueLabel] setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CoinValue"] ]];
    }
```

Anyone can help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the code since `totalBTCValue` and `totalUSDValue` are initialized until it's saved to `NSUserDefault`.

Comment: updated my code please help me...

Comment: Which line did you get the error?

Comment: I am getting the error while fetch the data from userDefaults

Comment: Where is the code you used to fetch the data from NSUserDefault?

Comment: I am fetching the data in another vc .I updated my question again please refer it

Comment: At the beginning, you post the code to do some stuff with `totalBTCValue`, `totalUSDValue` but now you say that the error is thrown when you fetch `PryvateCoinValue`. So what is the relationship between them? I really don't know what you are trying to explain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191303/discussion-between-angel-f-syrus-and-trungduc).

Comment: In my opinion, the code you added in question won't cause this issue. It may come from another place. It's easier to help if you can provide us the project or screen shot when you get crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your issue is because your code gets recursion.

As I understand, you used `NSNotificationCenter` to observer key `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification`. So whenever `NSUserDefaults` is updated, it will trigger `defaultsChanged` method. But inside it, you continue to change `NSUserDefaults`, set new value for `totalBTCValue` and `totalUSDValue` (as I guess) which makes `defaultsChanged` be called again and leads to recursion.

To fix the issue, you shouldn't update `NSUserDefaults` inside `defaultsChanged` method